# Mikva tumah zera tahara

Tags: mikvah-ritual-bath

So it sounds kind of ridiculous but i was once reading online about men using a womens mikva and somewhere it said  that they cant because they might get zera in the water and it impregnate the women lol obviously thats not why but it did get me thinking... wouldnt zera tumay up the water or would the mikva be metaher the water? I know it kind of sounds like purim torah but still curious.

Comment: also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13075/759

Comment: This laughable phenomenon apparently happened to Jeremiah's daughter. See [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=aqc-61vr4q0C&pg=PR15&lpg=PR15&dq=ben+zera&source=bl&ots=5s-BZAYCb3&sig=5wmGYY3Q8kfly6NlfgG-QdvvpEU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjn25Tc04vTAhVKwGMKHftPCdIQ6AEINTAG#v=onepage&q=ben%20zera&f=false).

Comment: @ezra https://www.sefaria.org/Chagigah.15a.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en